# How do you write a image to browser as a binary stream in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a service on a Coldfusion 9 server that creates image banners on the fly for us. A separate machine has to save these files with something like:

```
wget http://myserver.com/services/local/bannerCreator/250x250-v3.cfm?prodID=3&percentSaving=19
```

The problem is that I can't think of how to get coldfusion to write out binary data without using a temporary file. At the minute the image is just displayed as an image tag like this:

```
<cfimage action = "writeToBrowser" source="#banner#" width="#banner.width#" height="#banner.height#" />
```

Any ideas? Or should I just use a temporary file?

Answer (score 13):

I can't test because you're not giving any example code for how your images are generated, but have you tried something along this line?

```
<cfcontent reset="true" variable="#imageData#" type="image/jpg" />
```

---

Update: So I went ahead and created my own image; I'll assume you're doing something similar. This works perfectly for me:

```
<cfset img = imageNew("",200,200,"rgb","red") />
<cfcontent variable="#toBinary(toBase64(img))#" type="image/png" reset="true" />
```

This works without writing to file, and without using a virtual file system ("ramdisk")

Comment: Fyi: there is no need to explicitly set the reset attribute to `true`, because `true` is the default value.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the binary bytes of an file/image, you can replace the output buffer with it's contents like so:

```
<cfscript>
// eg. this is how you get a file as a binary stream
// var fileBytes = fileReadBinary( '/path/to/your/file.jpg' );

// get the http response
var response = getPageContext().getFusionContext().getResponse();

// set the appropriate mime type
response.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'image/jpg' );

// replace the output stream contents with the binary
response.getOutputStream().writeThrough( fileBytes );

// leave immediately to ensure no whitespace is added
abort;
</cfscript>
```

Pretty much what `<cfcontent>` does when you use `reset="true"`

The advantage of this method over `<cfcontent>` is that we can write it inside our cfscript based cfcs.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution above

```
<cfcontent variable="#toBinary(toBase64(img))#" type="image/png" reset="true" />
```

to not quite work for me.

Setting type="image/png" is just setting the mime type of the response. I don't think it's necessarily encoding the image as PNG.  As such, generating a transparent png (image type "argb") was giving me odd colours, when compared to the `<cfimage action = "writeToBrowser"...>` method.

I figured that somehow I needed to explicitly encode the image data as PNG and output the binary data directly.

With some digging around in the underlying java, I came up with this, which so far seems to work for me.

This example draws a transparent png with a black circle.

```
<!--- create the image and draw it --->
<cfset img = ImageNew("", 23, 23, "argb")>
<cfset ImageSetDrawingColor(img, "black")>
<cfset ImageDrawOval(img, 0, 0, 21, 21, true)>

<!--- get the response object --->
<cfset response = getPageContext().getFusionContext().getResponse()>
<!--- set the response mime type --->
<cfset response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png')>
<!--- get the underlying image data --->
<cfset bImage = ImageGetBufferedImage(img)>
<!--- get the magical object to do the png encoding --->
<cfset ImageIO = createObject("java", "javax.imageio.ImageIO")>
<!--- encode the image data as png and write it directly to the response stream --->
<cfset ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", response.getResponse().getOutputStream())>
```

I hope that helps someone!

Comment: Right, `cfcontent` only sets the `Content-Type` header (and optionally returns the content of a file or variable). Is not supposed to modify the content. What code gave you "odd colours compared to `writeToBrowser`"?

Comment: I got the odd colors with this code, Leigh: <cfset img = imageNew("",1,1,"argb","") />
<cfcontent variable="#toBinary(toBase64(img))#" type="image/png" reset="true" />  Thanks Ross!

Answer (score 3):

Take out the height and width attributes and add the format attribute:

```
<cfimage action = "writeToBrowser" source="#banner#" format="png" />
```

wget should honor the redirection to the physical file CF creates in the CFFileServlet folder but if it doesn't there is a flag you can set to make it `--max-redirect=10`.

And as you suggest, a temporary file would work too. Just write the file and use cfheader and cfcontent to write it out. Just make sure to make the temp file name more unique.

```
<cfimage action="write" destination="tempfile.png" source="#banner#" format="png" />
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=banner.png" />
<cfcontent file="tempfile.png" deletefile="true" type="image/png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I do a similar thing, and you need to combine using tags and cfscript.  There are image functions that are required.  There are a lot of image functions available, once you have an image in memory as a variable.     You can get the image into memory using CFFILE or CFHTTP or a number of other ways.

In my case, I read an image file into memory using CFIMAGE tag, then manipulate it with CFSCRIPT image functions by adding text to the bottom, then outputting the resulting image as a .png (or a .jpg if you prefer) to the browser.   The only file stored on the server is the original image file.  In your case instead of reading in an image you'd call it using a cfhttp tag as you already do.   Here's my code:

```
<!---Get the image for processing ...--->
<cfimage action="read" source="#application.approotABS#\webcam\webcam.jpg" name="CamImage" /> 
<!--- prepare the text for overlay --->
<cfscript>
  attr=structNew();
  attr.font = "Arial";
  attr.size = 15;
  ImageSetDrawingColor(CamImage, "white");
  ImageDrawText(CamImage, 'LIVE FROM STUDIO 1', 18,(ImageGetHeight(CamImage)-54), attr);
  ImageDrawText(CamImage, '#ShowOnNow.showname#', 18,(ImageGetHeight(CamImage)-36), attr);
  ImageDrawText(CamImage, datestring,18,(ImageGetHeight(CamImage)-18), attr);

</cfscript>

<!--- further down the page, output the manipulated image: ---->
 <div class="webcam">  
      <cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#Camimage#"  >
  </div>
```

You can see it in action at http://hawkesburyradio.com.au/index.cfm?pid=111538

(I am using CF9 with Windows Server )